# How can I hide a column in html table where it has a merged header

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table, in which I have a merged header for multiple columns. I need to hide/show some of the columns programmatically, and keep the merged header for the visible columns. the following is a sample of the table that I use. Any advice is much appreciated.

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center" field="Applicant" title="Funding Source" colspan="6" id="thi_cf_totalprjcost_2">Header 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col1</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col2</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col3</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col4</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col5</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1-1</td>
      <td>Cell 1-2</td>
      <td>Cell 1-3</td>
      <td>Cell 1-4</td>
      <td>Cell 1-5</td>
      <td>Cell 1-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2-1</td>
      <td>Cell 2-2</td>
      <td>Cell 2-3</td>
      <td>Cell 2-4</td>
      <td>Cell 2-5</td>
      <td>Cell 2-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3-1</td>
      <td>Cell 3-2</td>
      <td>Cell 3-3</td>
      <td>Cell 3-4</td>
      <td>Cell 3-5</td>
      <td>Cell 3-6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is a dynamic table created by a jQuery function, based on a JSON object retrieved from a database. In my code I have access to the table after loading the HTML page. The real table is much complex that the sample I posted here. So I prefer not to change the structure, if it is possible.

Comment: Would it not be similar to hiding a column without a merged header? Loop each row hiding the data, but instead of hiding a header just change the colspan?

Comment: If you don't need the data you are hiding, you could also possibly modify the function that generates your table in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns you want to hide ahead of time you can create CSS rules to facilitate the hiding then apply the appropriate class(es) to your table.

```css
table.hidesome thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(3) { display: none; }
table.hidesome tbody tr td:nth-child(3) { display: none; }
```

```html
<table class="hidesome" width="100%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th align="center" field="Applicant" title="Funding Source" colspan="6" id="thi_cf_totalprjcost_2">Header 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col1</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col2</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col3</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col4</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col5</th>
      <th width="10%" align="center">Col6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1-1</td>
      <td>Cell 1-2</td>
      <td>Cell 1-3</td>
      <td>Cell 1-4</td>
      <td>Cell 1-5</td>
      <td>Cell 1-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 2-1</td>
      <td>Cell 2-2</td>
      <td>Cell 2-3</td>
      <td>Cell 2-4</td>
      <td>Cell 2-5</td>
      <td>Cell 2-6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 3-1</td>
      <td>Cell 3-2</td>
      <td>Cell 3-3</td>
      <td>Cell 3-4</td>
      <td>Cell 3-5</td>
      <td>Cell 3-6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```